# TestFlight validation error when submitting to beta app review

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying to submit my app to beta app review through TestFlight in iTunesconnect. Ive been trying to do this a couple of days now but its just not working. First couple of days the progressbar was just spinning, and now it says "Validation Errors".

In the final step where im trying to submit the app, it just says "Validation errors". Not really helpful. Any idea what could be wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments by Zeezer, make sure you have everything filled out in the Test Information section of testflight on iTunesConnect [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuNfr.png).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I am actually having the same issue. Did you change anything in your entitlements?

For example I added Apple Pay support to an app but it validates fine directly from Xcode, does yours validate directly in Xcode Organiser?.

Mine throws the same error that you are showing here with no additional details.

Comment: I solved this by adding a policy url, strange!. It may be something different in your case but test to fill in more fields in test information.

Comment: It turned out to be an error in Apple's JS, I debugged the console and saw it was throwing an error on feedback email, which I had already populated. This thread on Reddit suggested that the it was caused by not having an English U.S Localisation (mine was only English U.K) and this fixed the issue. https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/654lh2/testflight_stuck_when_adding_build_to_external/

Answer (score 0):

As [zeezer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310470/zeezer) said you just be insure your test information filled in more 
full and correct , cause i have been searching for this issuss a coupple of days , and now it is solved upon zeezer's comments ,and thanks for zeezer's advise.